# Reinitlaizing jQuery after AJAX not working fully

Tags: jquery, ajax, magento

I'm trying to add a jQuery gallery to a dynamic php page that uses an AJAX menu to filter products (**Magento**). When a selectable menu item is released or the 'clear all' button is pushed to reload the original stack of products, my gallery reloads and the script doesn't fully come back. The correct spaces for the gallery images come back like empty placeholders but the images do not show up. 
This is the 2 seperate scripts I tried to reinitialize the gallery:

Current script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).bind('m-ajax-after')(function() {
        $('#gallery').finalTilesGallery();
    });
</script>
```

1st attempt:

```
jQuery(document).bind('m-ajax-after', function(e, selectors, url, action) {
    $('#gallery').finalTilesGallery();
});
```

Before I added this script the gallery wouldn't display at all so I know I'm at least on the right track.

It looks like the extension that m-ajax-after is referring to is ManaDev SEO Layered Navigation Plus. http://www.manadev.com/seo-layered-navigation-plus/
I've found in multiple forums around the internet they suggest using this snippet to reinitialize any jQuery after their menu reloads:

```
jQuery(document).bind('m-ajax-after', function (e, selectors, url, action) {
    // reinitialize your script 
});
```

They don't however offer any support as to how or why this works.

Comment: You are assuming that people reading this will know what that plugin is and where `'m-ajax-after'` event comes from. There are thousands of plugins...so that won;t be the case for most. Providing links to plugin docs might help

Comment: I had a feeling this is where we were headed. Let me get some more information together and edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling "m-ajax-after" doesn't really return much to work with. I can't find any documentation of this event, or what versions it applies to (or what it does).

But, **if** you have such an event, you're attaching it incorrectly:

```
$(document).bind('m-ajax-after') (function() {
```

The correct way to write it would be:

```
$(document).bind('m-ajax-after', function() {
```

Assuming that you haven't got an ancient version of jQuery though, there is a more prefered way:

```
$(document).on('m-ajax-after', function() {
```

You can easily test if this gets called when you expect, by adding for example an alert:

```
$(document).on('m-ajax-after', function() {
    alert('m-ajax-after invoked');
    $('#gallery').finalTilesGallery(); //Final Tiles Grid function apparently
});
```

Thing is though, that your *1st attempt* is correctly written, and probably should have worked. But it's worth trying without all the parameters, and with the alert.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I marked as answer because I believe there are other conflicts.

I tried the alert without any parameters related to the gallery or navigation. I also went looking through the ManaDev layered navigation js to see where 'm-ajax-after' was even coming from. This is what I found in their core.js file:
    _complete:function (options, url, data) {
        if (options.preventClicks) {
            this._preventClicks--;
         }
             $(document).trigger('m-ajax-after', [[], url, '', options]);
    }

The alert doesn't trigger.

Comment: @marshallbartist Then using *m-ajax-after* is probably not the answer (since it doesn't seem to be declared anywhere). I don't have expertise in Magento, but this link seem to have some good magento js events, and some tips how to identify them: http://alanstorm.com/magento_javascript_events

Comment: Thanks for the information on this, it was a big help! I didn't know if there was a trigger i could use. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I fell into the same issue, Check you haven't got more than one jQuery coming into the page